# Forking EPL library. Can I change license?

Tags: licensing, apache-license

There is library OpenCl.NET licensed under [Eclipse Public License](https://www.gnu.org/philosophy/license-list.html#EPL). I want to fork it to change some errors and add some functionality.

Is it possible to license my changes by Apache 2 license?

Comment: there is not enough details about that library to answer this. What is its license?

Comment: @gnat [Eclipse Public License](https://www.gnu.org/philosophy/license-list.html#EPL). Abbreviation ‘EPL’ is quite common and even less ambiguous than, say, ‘GPL’ with ‘GNU’ omitted.

Comment: As for the question; the title is misleading (of course, you can *not* *change* the license from a more restrictive in some points to a less restrictive); but the body (whether it possible to cover *your changes* by [ASLv2](https://www.gnu.org/licenses/license-list.html#apache2)) may be rephrased as ‘Is ASLv2 EPL-compatible?’; and that is valid and interesting question; but why on earth it bothers you? Why don’t you want to cover your changes (which are not so drastic, I guess) with the same EPL?

Comment: @DmitryAlexandrov It was a bit hard to understand EPL then I read that for a first time.

Comment: The license states _"...must be made available under this Agreement"_. It's *this* license, not *this or some other*, so I don't see how one could possibly think there'd be another option.

Comment: @buldo Thanks, but I am still wondering, what wrong do you see in applying EPL to your additions.

Comment: @DmitryAlexandrov for now I think nothing wrong. But it still interesting question for me.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

<sub>I am not a lawyer. You should get one, if you are concerned about possible legal issues.</sub>

---

The title of questions (‘Can I change license?’) does not match its body (‘Is it possible to license my changes by Apache v2 license?’).

Of course, you can not *change* the license. Even most permissive free software licenses, such as [Expat](https://directory.fsf.org/wiki/License:Expat) and [2-clause BSD](https://directory.fsf.org/wiki/License:FreeBSD) licenses¹, do not allow *changing* the license of original code – they only allow *sub-licensing*, i. e. basically covering it by another *less* permissive license in addition to original. [Eclipse Public License v1.0](http://www.eclipse.org/org/documents/epl-v10.php), does not allow sub-licensing sources under different terms² (so it should be considered [copyleft](https://www.gnu.org/copyleft/) license); and even if it did, ASLv2 is *more* permissive; thus **no**, you cannot take OpenCl.NET, modify it, and redistribute it under Apache License.

As for whether it is possible to cover your changes by [Apache [Software] License v2](http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0.txt), this may be rephrased as ‘Is ASLv2 is compatible with EPLv1?’, and [according to EPL FAQ](http://www.eclipse.org/legal/eplfaq.php#3RDPARTY) the answer is yes. So **yes**, you can attach ASLv2 to *your changes*, and incorporate them into the original library. The result of *as a whole* might and should be considered as covered by EPL.

However, I do not understand, why you don’t just use the same license as original library does.

---

<sup>¹ Well, there is an ultimately permissive license – [WTFPL](http://www.wtfpl.net/txt/copying) :-), it do allow changing the license.

² § 3: *When the Program is made available in source code form: a) it must be made available under this Agreement...*</sup>

Comment: This advice feels dangerous to me.  I'd *definitely* consult a Lawyer before traveling this route.  At best I might feel safe distributing diffs/patches under my own license, but trying to attach another license to someone else's source code without their explicit buy-in seems ill-advised.

Comment: @tjd Ⓐ I actually said nothing about attaching another license to *someone else’s* work in the third paragraph of my answer, since Buldo wants to apply a license to *his own* work. Ⓑ However, the situation indeed might be generalized – you might want to include someone else’s ASL-covered work into EPL-covered product; and **yes**, you would still allowed to do it. Copyright holders gave you quite explicit permission, see § 4 of ASLv2. (Note also, that those who use, say, Expat license do not make the permission so explicit, however you are still allowed to attach another license above Expat.)

Answer (score 8):

From the EPLv1.0

> 3. REQUIREMENTS
>
> A Contributor may choose to distribute the Program in object code form
>   under its own license agreement, provided that:
>
> a) it complies with the terms and conditions of this Agreement; and
>
> b) its license agreement:
>
> ```
> i) effectively disclaims on behalf of all Contributors all
>    warranties and conditions, express and implied, including
>    warranties or conditions of title and non-infringement, and
>    implied warranties or conditions of merchantability and fitness
>    for a particular purpose;
>
> ii) effectively excludes on behalf of all Contributors all
>     liability for damages, including direct, indirect, special,
>     incidental and consequential damages, such as lost profits;
>
> iii) states that any provisions which differ from this Agreement
>      are offered by that Contributor alone and not by any other
>      party; and
>
> iv) states that source code for the Program is available from such
>     Contributor, and informs licensees how to obtain it in a
>     reasonable manner on or through a medium customarily used for
>     software exchange.
> ```
>
> When the Program is made available in source code form:
>
> a) it must be made available under this Agreement; and
>
> b) a copy of this Agreement must be included with each copy of the
>   Program.
>
> Contributors may not remove or alter any copyright notices contained
>   within the Program.

So a basic "I AM NOT A LAWYER" interpretation is that you can only distribute the source code under the EPL. Object code can be under a different license under certain conditions.

Comment: @Buldo asked a very unclear question, which consists of two essentially different ones: ‘Can I change license?’ and ‘Is it possible to license *my changes* by Apache 2 license?’. It seems, that you addressed the first and  ignored the second; but, I think, it would be better to state it explicitly.

Comment: The second ‘Is it possible to license my changes by Apache 2 license?’ Is sort of covered by the first. "When the Program is made available in source code form: a) it must be made available under this Agreement; [the EPL] ".

Comment: Do not they require opposite answers: the first – no, the second – yes? (See my answer below.)

Comment: The statement in the license looks pretty clear to me "a) it [the source code] must be made available under this Agreement;". Of course the changes could be made available independently under any license.

Comment: The question then becomes, if I change the code a little bit, is it still "the Program" as referred to in the license? Or are derivative works considered to be independent entities from "the Program", and thus this would not apply? The definition of "the Program" from the license may be relevant. (Yes, this is pedantic, but alas, such is the nature of licenses.)

Comment: @Jaydee, yes this statement is pretty clearly makes EPL copyleft license; but how does this prevent to sub-licensing an ASLv2-covered code under EPL?

Comment: " I want to fork it to change some errors and add some functionality. Is it possible to license my changes by Apache 2 license? ". So buldo can license his code under anything he likes. However the total of the forked code (including his changes) can only be licensed under the EPL. He cannot release the entire fork under the Apache license.